# Error: too many renders al modificar un objeto

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, javascript-objeto

Soy nuevo en *react* llevo apenas un mes y cuando estaba haciendo este componente me dio error:

> Error: too many renders al modificar un objeto

El componente que realizo es un menú sider y la funcionalidad que trataba de darle era que cuando estuviera en la dirección que tuviera el mismo path que el botón cambiara de color, para eso quise utilizar **`useState`** guardando un objeto con booleanos dejándolos en **`false`** por defecto, y use `window.onload` para lanzar la función al cargar la pagina pero cuando intento modificar el objeto con `setState` me da error y empieza a renderizarse en loop infinito, pero no se porque, acabo de leer en la documentación y vi que estaba correcto como hice.

```
import "./MenuSider.scss";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function MenuSider() {
  let pathActual = window.location.pathname;
  const paths = {
    home: "/admin",
    menuWeb: "/admin/menu-web",
    homeName: "home",
    menuWebName: "menuWeb",
  };
  const [pathVerify, setPathVerify] = useState({
    home: false,
    menuWeb: false,
  });

  const comparePath = () => {
    if (pathActual === paths.home) {
      setPathVerify({ ...pathVerify, home: true });
    } else {
      setPathVerify({ ...pathVerify, home: false });
    }
    if (pathActual === paths.menuWeb) {
      setPathVerify({ ...pathVerify, menuWeb: true });
    } else {
      setPathVerify({ ...pathVerify, menuWeb: false });
    }
  };

  window.onload = comparePath();

  return (
    <div className="menu-sider">
      <button
        type="link"
        className={
          pathVerify.home ? "menu-sider__button active" : "menu-sider__button"
        }
      >
        <Link to="/admin" className="menu-sider__element">
          <span className="material-icons menu-sider__element-icon">home</span>
          <span className="menu-sider__element-text">Inicio</span>
        </Link>
      </button>

      <button
        type="link"
        className={
          pathVerify.menuWeb
            ? "menu-sider__button active"
            : "menu-sider__button"
        }
      >
        <Link to="/admin/menu-web" className="menu-sider__element">
          <span className="material-icons menu-sider__element-icon">list</span>
          <span className="menu-sider__element-text">
            {pathVerify.menuWeb ? "Menu web" : "Mano webo"}
          </span>
        </Link>
      </button>
      <button
        type="link"
        className="menu-sider__button"
        onClick={() => console.log(pathActual, pathVerify)}
      >
        <div className="menu-sider__element">
          <span className="material-icons menu-sider__element-icon">list</span>
          <span className="menu-sider__element-text">Boton de prueba</span>
        </div>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema creo, es que en cada render estás ejecutando la función `comparePath`, y esa función hace un llamado a `setPathVerify`, lo que causa un nuevo render... y por eso el ciclo infinito.

Yo creo que el problema está en que a `windows.onload` le estás asignando el resultado de la ejecución de comparePath... creo que lo que quisiste hacer mejor es:

```
window.onload = comparePath;
```